# Halley's Comet duration of visibility

Tags: halleys-comet

When Halley's Comet is visible in the sky, how long does that last? Is it only visible for a week or is it up there for a month, or several months? What I'm actually wondering is, though it arrived in 1910, could it still have been visible in the sky into 1911?

Answer (score 2):

Typically it was visible a few weeks only, about 3...6 months at most. There is an excellent summary in [Broughton (1979)](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1979JRASC..73...24B). In 1910 the peak visibility was in April, the last recorded sighting of Halley without instrumentation on 13th June.
[Yeonan (1986)](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu//full/1986JRASC..80...62Y/0000077.000.html) gives an overview including instrumentation; while it has positional and brightness data for dates in 1911, they are for a magnitude > 10, thus far beyond being visible with the naked eye.

So no, in 1911 Halley was not visible anymore without then bleeding-edge astronomical telescopes.